# How To Logout user from specific session in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, session, authentication, logout, laravel-5.7

Im trying to implement , user login history and allow user to logout from specific device

Im using `SESSION_DRIVER=database` and have `sessions` table in database
as per [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#introduction)

[image]

i have `user_logins` table with below structure :

> **session_id |user_id | ip_address | user_agent | browser_name |
>   location | login_at | is_active**

Im success fully able to store above information in table `user_logins` using [UserEventSubscriber](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events#event-subscribers) `handleUserLogin` function

now i want to logout a user from a specific device , how to do it ?

I m able to delete entry from `user_logins` table with `ip_address` and `user_agent` but I also want to logout that user from specific device.

anyone please help me to solve this .

Answer (score 2):

put this method in your controller and set suitable route to execute

```php
public function removeSession($id){
    \Session::getHandler()->destroy($id);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: visit this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session when you store sessions in database table name should be `sessions`

Comment: yes i have 2 tables , `sessions` <-- which is storing as default , and custom table `user_logins` table for saving device logins history

Answer (score 0):

```
public function authLogoutForOccGolf(Request $request) {
    $request->session()->flush();       
    return redirect('/');       
}
```

Comment: this will flush all session of currently logged in user , i want to delete a single session of user who is logged in multiple devices